# HTML select option selected does not work

Tags: php, html, html-select

**I want to set the current date by default but it works only on year's select (the last one).**

I wouldn't like to use javascript in this case. Just **html** and **php**.

I have already tried "selected='selected'" and "autocomplete=off" as shown in different other posts.

Here my code

```
<form id="form-orders-date" onsubmit="selectOrdersDate();">
                    <select id="orders-day">
                        <?php 
                        for ($i=1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
                            if (sprintf('%02d', $i) == date("d")) {
                                echo "<option value=\"".sprintf('%02d', $i)."\" selected>".sprintf('%02d', $i)."</option>";
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "<option value=\"".sprintf('%02d', $i)."\">".sprintf('%02d', $i)."</option>" ;
                            }
                        } 
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <select id="orders-month">
                        <?php 
                        for ($i=1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
                            if (sprintf('%02d', $i) == date("m")) {
                                echo "<option value=\"".sprintf('%02d', $i)."\" selected>".sprintf('%02d', $i)."</option>";
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "<option value=\"".sprintf('%02d', $i)."\">".sprintf('%02d', $i)."</option>" ;
                            }
                        } 
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <select id="orders-year">
                        <?php 
                        for ($i=2012; $i <= 2020; $i++) {
                            if (sprintf('%02d', $i) == date("Y")) {
                                echo "<option value=\"".sprintf('%02d', $i)."\" selected>".sprintf('%02d', $i)."</option>";
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "<option value=\"".sprintf('%02d', $i)."\">".sprintf('%02d', $i)."</option>" ;
                            }
                        } 
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

here the plain HTML when the PHP has been run:

```html
<form id="form-orders-date" onsubmit="selectOrdersDate();">
    <select id="orders-day">
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02" selected>02</option>
        <option value="03">03</option>
        <option value="04">04</option>
        <option value="05">05</option>
        <option value="06">06</option>
        <option value="07">07</option>
        <option value="08">08</option>
        <option value="09">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>
    <select id="orders-month">
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        <option value="03" selected>03</option>
        <option value="04">04</option>
        <option value="05">05</option>
        <option value="06">06</option>
        <option value="07">07</option>
        <option value="08">08</option>
        <option value="09">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <select id="orders-year">
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017" selected>2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add the plain HTML when the PHP has been run? It makes it easier to read.

Comment: yes, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code you are looking for
Remember to use single quotes (') when including double quotes inside the PHP echo or else if using double quotes use " inside the outer double quotes.

```
<form id="form-orders-date" onsubmit="selectOrdersDate();">
    <select id="orders-day">
      <?php
      for ($i=1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
        if ($i == date("d")) {
          echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$i.'</option>';
        }
        else{
          echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
        }
      }
      ?>
    </select>
    <select id="orders-month">
      <?php
      for ($i=1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        if ($i == date("m")) {
          echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$i.'</option>';
        }
        else{
          echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
        }
      }
      ?>
    </select>
    <select id="orders-year">
      <?php
      for ($i=2012; $i <= 2020; $i++) {
        if ($i == date("Y")) {
          echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$i.'</option>';
        }
        else{
          echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
        }
      }
      ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: thank you, it works well but I don't understand why, I mean: the final HTML generated code is exactly the same, with the "selected" options in the same places

Comment: as I said use single quotes (') when including double quotes insite the php echo or else if using double quotes use \" inside the outer double quotes.

Comment: That means $name = "ilrenzo";
echo "My name is "".$name.""; will not work
but:
echo 'My name is "'.$name.'"; will work.
The output will be:
My name is "ilrenzo"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this.

```
<form id="form-orders-date" onsubmit="selectOrdersDate();">
<select id="orders-day">
<?php 
    for ($i=1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
       if ($i == date("d")) {
            echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
       } else {
           echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
       }
    } 
?>                  
</select>
<select id="orders-month">
   for ($i=1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
      if ($i == date("m")) {
         echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
      } else {
         echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
      }
   }            
</select>
<select id="orders-year">
<?php 
   for ($i=2012; $i <= 2020; $i++) {
   if ($i == date("Y")) {
        echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
   } else {
       echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
   }
}              
?>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more compact way of achieving this:

```
<form id="form-orders-date" onsubmit="selectOrdersDate();">
    <select id="orders-day">
        <?php for ($d = 1; $d <= 31; $d++) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $d; ?>" <?php if ($d == date('j')) { echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo $d; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <select id="orders-month">
        <?php for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $m; ?>" <?php if ($m == date('n')) { echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo $m; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <select id="orders-year">
        <?php for ($y = 2012; $y <= 2020; $y++) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $y; ?>" <?php if ($y == date('Y')) { echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo $y; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you tried this already, but your sample code doesn't show it. Here's how your  tag should be formed:

```
<select>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02" selected="selected">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Your example above looks very different for the selected element. I'd suggest using whatever inspection tool is built into your web browser to see what exactly was rendered, and that will probably make it the solution obvious.

For reference, see:

[Definition of select tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

[Definition of option tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried autocomplete="off" for select? It works for me.